# YouTube Player API for iframe Embeds doesn't work seekTo method on Microsoft Edge

Tags: youtube-api

Recently, YouTube Player API for iframe Embeds doesn't work seekTo method on Microsoft Edge (Windows 10).
Example, simple HTML5 player as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div class="video-container">
        <div id="player">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var tag = document.createElement('script');
        tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
        var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
        var player;
        var isPlayerReady = false;

        function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
            isPlayerReady = true;
            window.external.notify("ready");
        }
        function startVideo(videoId) {
            if (!isPlayerReady) return;
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                videoId: videoId,
                playerVars: {
                    'autoplay': 1,
                    'autohide': 2,
                    'fs': 0,
                    'cc_load_policy': 0,
                    'enablejsapi': 1,
                    'iv_load_policy': 3,
                    'loop': 0,
                    'modestbranding': 1,
                    'rel': 0,
                    'showinfo': 1,
                },
                events: {
                }
            });
        }
        function onSeek(sec) {
            if (player == null) return;
            player.seekTo(sec, true);
        }
    </script>
<a onclick="startVideo('XefNxZ0pAR0');">Start</a>
<br />
<a onclick="onSeek(60);">Seek</a>
</body>
</html>
```

If click the 'seek' link, error occurred "Object doesn't support property or method 'seekTo'".
And after start Video, error always occurred 'invalid argument' in www-embed-player.js (565,52)
[image]

What's happened? Before few weeks, this code could run on Edge.